# How to make mount --bind permanent?

Tags: 14.04, mount, fstab

When I am doing:

```
mount --bind dirone dirtwo
```

After OS reboot the binding is lost.

I am checking binded dirs in `/proc/mounts`

How can I make these binds permanent without clogging up `/etc/fstab` ?

Here's one entry from `/proc/mounts`

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/4f5082d7-aba2-4bc7-8d64-3bbb3d773aab /home/username/dir ext4 rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
```

Comment: You have to either run that command during boot (rc.local) or put an entry in /etc/fstab. What makes you think this is clogging up /etc/fstab ? , this is what fstab is for, fstab is much "cleaner" then rc.local

Answer (score 45, accepted):

What do you mean "clogging up `/etc/fstab`"? The best place to put this in *is* `/etc/fstab`; that's what it was made for!

All you have to do is add one line after the first mount:

```
# <device>                                 <dir>                 <type>  <options>                 <dump>  <pass>
UUID=288a84bf-876c-4c4b-a4ba-d6b4cc6fc0d2  /mnt/device            ext4    defaults,noatime,nofail   0       2
/mnt/device                                /srv/binded_device     none    bind                      0       0
```

Comment: So you recommend just copy/paste from `/proc/mounts` to `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: Yes, that should work. Just copy both the original mount and the `mount --bind`

Comment: Thanks, but `mount --bind` doesn't saved in `/proc/mounts` ?

Comment: No, I guess it doesn't; but, it shouldn't be _too_ hard to copy the first mount then add your own for `mount --bind`.

Comment: just like in your example instead of `rw,relatime,data=ordered` type `bind`, right?

Comment: Well, you need both lines. The first the line is the actual mounting of the device. The second line is to "`mount --bind`" the device to another location.

Comment: I met a problem, my source dir and target dir contains a space character, "/home/alfred/Tencent Files", I tried with fail(even adding `\` before space), how to mount such a directory?

Answer (score 40):

The easiest way is to *mount --bind* what you need like

```
mount --bind /home/sda1/Windows/Users/Me/Dropbox ~/Dropbox
```

Then open *mtab*

```
sudo nano /etc/mtab
```

Copy your line like

```
/home/sda1/Windows/Users/Me/Dropbox /home/me/Dropbox none rw,bind 0 0
```

and paste it in *fstab* so it would mount on reboot

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

If you folder is on mounted disk make sure your binding line comes after disk mount

Comment: this should be the accepted solution.

Comment: Dont edit /etc/mtab directly, its a symbolic link, so you will get errors if you edit it directly. More importantly, edit /etc/fstab. /etc/mtab reflects the changes in /etc/fstab. You are basically putting the same settings in a different file so why not use /etc/fstab?

Comment: @Dave, you misread. @dgpro is not talking about editing `/etc/mtab`, he's talking about copying the line that will appear in that file after using the `mount` command to `/etc/fstab`.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution (which is helpful when you're using LVM and the accepted answer will not work and some may consider more useful since it uses a bit more logic.  Another use case scenario where this is the preferred option is if you're using encrypted partitions that require a password so you'd want to make sure that it doesn't attempt to mount there before the volume is mounted.) would be doing something similar to this:

Append the following to your crontab

# crontab -l | tail -1 ; cat /usr/sbin/custom-compiler-mount

```
@reboot /usr/sbin/custom-compiler-mount
```

Essentially you would use crond to execute a script on reboot

```
#!/bin/bash
( until [[ $( (mount |& grep vg0-homevol 2>&1 9<&1 > /dev/null 1<&9) ) ]] ; 
do 
sleep 1 
done & wait;mount -o rbind /home/linuxgeek/experimental/s3/gcc/ /gcc & ) & >/dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a "per user" mount and not a system-wide mount, rather than using `mount --bind` or creating an `/etc/fstab` entry, why not use a symlink?

```
ln --symbolic target_dir access_point_of_target_dir
```

Add this line to the bottom of your user's `.profile` file to have it available automagically on login, without creating a system-wide `fstab` entry, and without needing root permissions like you will when putting `mount --bind` in a script.

It's not a perfect solution, but I have found that in most cases a symbolic link performs the same as having access to the physical directory.

Comment: This doesn't work for snaps, which is the default for many tools on an Ubuntu system. This is my use case, but symlinks make snaps fail. Using a bind mount makes it work.

Comment: Some tools like IDE get confused: in some of their internals, they call `realpath`, but not everywhere. In result you never know whether it's gonna remember a linked path or real. With bind mounts they don't know.