# Mount secondary hard drive for several users in respective home folders

Tags: permissions, mount, hard-drive

I have a shared secondary hard drive which is now mounted in `/media/tyrion/data` and that is accessible for all users on my family computer.

However, I wish it to be automatically mounted at login in the user's respective home folder. Is this possible? The reason for this is that I want snap apps that by nature (?) have access to the home folder only to be able to access shared files on this disk. Or is there a simpler solution to this (I guess not that uncommon) problem?

Comment: do you need to automount the drive at startup? or is that part taken care of already?

Comment: It's automatically mounted at start up now. Does this answer your question?

Comment: use mount --bind . Not sure exactly what and why your are doing all this so hard to know if there is a better way. I do not use snap. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/550348/how-to-make-mount-bind-permanent and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount , see "Linux bind mount " section.

Comment: yes. one method  to give all users access is to make a symlink to the drive in each persons home folder. Note: everyone will need write permissions on the drive.

Comment: thanks, I added symlinks for all users in their home folders, which works like a charm (every user has full access to the secondary hdd). However, I installed a few snap apps (e.g. krita) and none of them can make use of the link. For the snaps the symlink folder is there but empty. Any suggestions?