# How to move 'snap' folder to another location?

Tags: 18.04, directory, home-directory, snap

I used some snaps on my system and I found a `snap` folder in my home. I would like to know if there is a safe way to move the `snap` folder to another location, away from the home folder.

I read answers to [Move snap packages to another location/directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029562/move-snap-packages-to-another-location-directory), but the question is different.

Comment: +1 and how to create a working symbolic link from AnotherLocation/snap to ~/snap ?