# "failed to mount Mount unit for <program>" when restarting the system

Tags: boot, mount, snap

[image: boot messages with errors]

When I restart my Ubuntu 18.04 system, it suddenly crashes and shows a long list of `[FAILED]` messages as shown above, for example:

```
[FAILED] Failed to mount Mount unit for gtk-common-themes, revision 1198
See 'systemctl status "snap-gtk\\x2dcommon\\x2dthemes-1198.mount"' for details
```

and other mount errors like

```
[FAILED] Failed to mount FUSE Control File System
```

What could be the problem here, and how can I fix it?

Comment: I welcome to ask ubuntu. If you can copy and paste the output of the error into your question and wrap it in code brackets {} that would be awesome. thanks!

Comment: Thanks@Joshua Besneatte however I am getting error in boot level I took pictures but cannot upload here it's giving me error while upload pictures in ask Ubuntu

Comment: The error will be stored in /var/log/  (probably kern.log or syslog) Oh and regarding the image: you need the 1st error... what you show us are results from a previous problem.

Comment: thanks@ Rinzwind sorry when I restart my laptop only this error come on my screen

Comment: Looks like you have a corrupt system. You can boot into Live Ubuntu and try running [fsck](https://www.tecmint.com/fsck-repair-file-system-errors-in-linux/) to repair the system. If that doesn't work and you don't have a an image back-up of your system, you're looking at a re-install.

Answer (score 7):

If you deleted snap files manually, for instance, in order to clean up space, some `.mount` files were left in `/etc/systemd/system/`, like `/etc/systemd/system/snap-core20-975.mount`.

You can try the following command:

```sh
grep -r What /etc/systemd/system/ | sed -E 's/.*What=(.*)/\1/g' | xargs ls -la {}
```

The output will be:

```sh
ls: cannot access '/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snap-postman_81.snap': No such file or directory
-rw------- 2 root root  64233472 Mai 19 22:11 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/****.snap
....
```

So, now you know what snaps are missing and can decide what to do, e.g. remove obsolete `.mount` files.

Comment: I ended up doing `apt purge snapd` and it rebuilt everything after messing up moving the /var/lib/snapd to a partition. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029562/move-snap-packages-to-another-location-directory/1398092#1398092