# Can I share docker overlay2 between two host systems?

Tags: dual-boot, mount, hard-drive, docker, symbolic-link

I would like to install on my local computer two systems, eg.: Ubuntu and Arch.

I know that all libraries, system settings, user settings should be distinct for these systems.

But in case of:

- docker (/var/lib/docker/overlay2)
- snap (/var/lib/snapd/snaps)

I do not suspect differences and want to mount these directories to the same disc space for both systems.

**Should it works stable, or should I suspect problems from this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to share the folders between the two distributions.

In case of the docker daemon, the `/var/lib/docker` folder can be "[moved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50707738/move-docker-var-run-docker-data-to-different-directory)" to a different location by modifying the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` configuration file.

The same is possible for [snapd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029562/move-snap-packages-to-another-location-directory).

**However, the versions of `dockerd` and `snapd` must be identical!**. If the version of `dockerd` or `snapd` are different, the "older" version will fail.