# snap is broken because of moving files

Tags: 20.04, permissions, mount, snap

I had a nearly full / drive.
Thats the reason why I moved the content of /snap on a own partition.

I stopped snap, moved the content, mount the new partition and started snap.

/etc/fstab

```
/dev/HDD/snap /snap ext4 defaults 0   1
```

When i try to install Chromium i get this error:

```
sudo snap install chromium
Fehler: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Den Konfigurationshook von Snap "chromium" ausführen, falls vorhanden (run hook "configure": cannot locate base snap core18: No such file or directory)
```

ll /snap

```
insgesamt 56
drwxr-xr-x 13 root         root         4096 Jan  4 10:27 ./
drwxr-xr-x 20 root         root         4096 Dez 29 10:02 ../
drwxr-xr-x  3 root         root         4096 Dez 18 00:30 anbox/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root         root         4096 Jan  4 10:27 bin/
drwx------  4 jokergermany jokergermany 4096 Dez 18 00:24 carnet/
drwx------  4 root         root         4096 Dez 18 00:25 core/
drwx------  4 root         root         4096 Dez 18 00:26 core18/
drwxr-xr-x  4 root         root         4096 Dez 18 00:26 gnome-3-28-1804/
drwxr-xr-x  4 root         root         4096 Dez 18 00:27 gtk-common-themes/
drwx------  2 root         root         4096 Dez 18 00:27 lost+found/
-r--r--r--  1 root         root          548 Dez 18 00:16 README
drwxr-xr-x  4 root         root         4096 Dez 18 00:27 snapd/
drwxr-xr-x  3 root         root         4096 Dez 18 00:27 software-boutique/
drwxr-xr-x  3 root         root         4096 Dez 18 00:27 ubuntu-mate-welcome/
```

snap list

```
Name                 Version                     Rev    Aufzeichnung     Herausgeber       Hinweise
anbox                4-56c25f1                   186    latest/beta      morphis           devmode
carnet               0.22.1                      16     latest/stable    alexandre-roux-m  -
core                 16-2.48                     10577  latest/stable    canonical✓        core
core18               20201210                    1944   latest/stable    canonical✓        base
gnome-3-28-1804      3.28.0-19-g98f9e67.98f9e67  145    latest/stable    canonical✓        -
gtk-common-themes    0.1-50-gf7627e4             1514   latest/stable    canonical✓        -
snapd                2.48.1                      10492  latest/stable    canonical✓        snapd
software-boutique    0+git.f633ffb               54     latest/stable/…  flexiondotorg     classic
ubuntu-mate-welcome  20.10.0-bb92cef1            575    latest/stable    flexiondotorg     classic
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: You will probably need to do a bit more work with mount points. Take a look at the third option in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1070635/1091774), and you'll see the mount points that need to be managed. I'd say you're more than halfway there, though 

Comment: You mean that i should change the mount point for /var/lib/snapd aswell?
Do i have to?

Comment: /dev/HDD/snap seems to be non-existent.

Comment: my /snap directories have drwxr-xr-x permissions and are all owned by root - maybe a chmod and chown is needed   ---- drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 jan  5 16:53 bin
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 jan  5 21:16 core
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 jan  5 11:51 core18
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 jan  4 19:55 core20

Comment: Thansk for your help. Setting the permissions didn't work.
dev/hdd/snap exists:
mount | grep snap
```
/dev/mapper/HDD-snap on /snap type ext4 (rw,relatime)
```
I will purge snap now...

Comment: It doesn't make sense to move the contents of `/snap` to a different partition. The directory contains a README file, read it: `The disk space consumed by the content under this directory is
minimal as the real snap content never leaves the .snap file.
Snaps are *mounted* rather than unpacked.`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i gave up.

```
sudo apt-get purge snapd snap 
sudo apt-get install snapd snap
```

and everything is working

Comment: if you remove snap and snapd system may broke !

Answer (score 0):

Finally! After reboot:

```
sudo apt-get purge snapd snap  
sudo apt-get install snapd snap
sudo snap install snap-store
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem on me when reinstall snap-store on Ubuntu 22.04

Run configure hook of "snap-store" snap if present (run hook "configure": cannot locate base snap core20: No such file or directory)

I solved it by reinstalling "core20":

`sudo snap remove core20`

then

`sudo snap install core20`

[Cannot locate base snap core20: No such file or directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1434765/cannot-locate-base-snap-core20-no-such-file-or-directory)