# Move gdm to boot partition on another drive

Tags: boot, partitioning, kde, bootloader, gdm

I am currently trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 on an Acer Aspire Laptop which has a 14GB Nvme drive and a 1TB HDD drive installed.

**Current configuartion:**

The /boot/efi /boot and swap partition is located at the 14GB nvme drive and the root (/) location ist at the 1TB HDD drive.
This configuration is still causing a super slow bootup because it needs a lot of time to load the display manager and the desktop envoirement.

**What I want to do:**

My Idea was to move the display manager (gdm in my case) and the desktop envoirement (kde-plasma) to the 14GB nvme drive so my Laptop boots up faster.
But how can I do this!?

Answer (score 0):

- swap partition? why? We stopped using that years ago. We nowadays use a swapfile.
- The display manager is NOT 1 file or 1 directory. It, like all Linux system files, spread over a lot of directories based on functionality.

> But how can I do this!?

Install / on the NVME disk.

I would advice to install `/` on the NVME. 14Gb is enough for the system IF you keep it clean of personal files. So use the hdd for the /home/$USER/ directories (see `./config/users-dirs.dirs` on how to do that) and  move anything snap related to the hdd (see [Move snap packages to another location/directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029562/move-snap-packages-to-another-location-directory) )