# Snap and System broken

Tags: 20.04, snap

As I was running low on space I tried to move my snap to another disk following the answer from Muhammad here: [Move snap packages to another location/directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029562/move-snap-packages-to-another-location-directory)

It broke everything and I cant get it back... I tried running several times the steps to revert but nothing works. Please help me, I am new to Ubuntu and it feels like my system is broken...

This is what I ran initially:

```
#Stop auto-updating (will *not* crash snaps already open)
sudo systemctl mask snapd.service
sudo systemctl stop snapd.service
sudo systemctl disable snapd.service

#Copy the data
sudo rsync -avzP /var/lib/snapd/  /mnt/EC89002B88FFF246/Ubuntu/snap/snapd/

#Do backups
sudo mv /var/lib/snapd /var/lib/snapd.bak
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak

#Change fstab (Change $USER with your name or change the path totally)
echo "/mnt/EC89002B88FFF246/Ubuntu/snap /var/lib/snapd none bind 0 0" | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab

#remount fstab Or reboot.
sudo mkdir /var/lib/snapd
sudo mount -a

if ls  /var/lib/snapd/ | grep snaps
then
    echo "Re-mounting snapd folder is done successfully. !!!!"
    sudo rm -rf /var/lib/snapd.bak
else
    echo "WARNING : Re-mounting snapd folder failed, please revert !!!!! "
    echo "WARNING : Re-mounting snapd folder failed, please revert !!!!! "
    echo "WARNING : Re-mounting snapd folder failed, please revert !!!!! "
    echo "WARNING : Re-mounting snapd folder failed, please revert !!!!! "
    echo "WARNING : Re-mounting snapd folder failed, please revert !!!!! "

    # Trying to revert automatically
    sudo cp /etc/fstab.bak /etc/fstab

    sudo mount -a
    sudo umount /var/lib/snapd

    sudo mv /var/lib/snapd.bak /var/lib/snapd

    echo "Files located at ~/snap/snapd should be removed, but are kept for
    recovery until you, manually reboot the system and make sure the service
    is running correctly. Then you can manually remove the folder ~/snap/snapd
    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!, you should do that manually."

fi

#Restart auto-updating
sudo systemctl unmask snapd.service
sudo systemctl start snapd.service
sudo systemctl reenable snapd.service
```

I am not expert but it seems like it did not restore properly var/lib/snap:
[Disk Analyzer output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cf9sa.png)

Please help me

Comment: At what point did it go wrong, and what was the error message?

Comment: That link says to move snap apps not the snap environment which you can not do. If you want a stable OS and the quickest fix reinstall.

Comment: Is there a way to revert snap and then I would reinstall all the apps I use?
Right now, here are the problems:
- It takes even more storage (probably the backups but I am afraid to delete anything now). I have only 700MB left which was not the case before
- None of the snap apps work correctly
- When I boot, I see a bunch of [FAILED] such as core18 (there are many of FAILED). I know that it was a snap-installed app.

Comment: If I want to reinstall snap from scratch, can I just deletee every folder related to snap and then run:
`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install snapd`

`sudo snap install snap-store`

Are they any necessary files on snap for my system? If not, why do I see some fails when I boot my system?